# does NFS proto=rdma bypass firewalld?

Tags: rhel, firewalld, nfsv4, rdma

in `/etc/firewalld/zone/mycustomzone.xml` I use the syntax of `<port protocol="tcp" port="2049"/>` to open port number being a protocol choice of either `tcp` or `udp`.  For NFSv4 only port 2049 needs to be opened, so when NFS `proto=tcp` then open firewall port protocol tcp.  And when NFS proto=udp then firewalld protocol=udp.

Are there other valid choices besides `tcp` and `udp` there for firewalld?

Using RHEL 8.7 with NFS v4.2 working, when doing `mount` it reports my mounts typically having `proto=tcp`.  But when I have RDMA working it says `proto=rdma`.

I know RDMA happens over port 20049 (by default).  What is the relationship of RDMA to TCP/UDP, and do I just need to do both

```
<port protocol="tcp" port="2049"/>
<port protocol="udp" port="2049"/>
```

in my firewalld xml file where both protocols need to be allowed for RDMA?  Or should only one of those two be opened and if so which one?  I don't think firewalld supports *protocol=rdma* does it?

**update:**

- the original title to this post was *NFS proto=rdma and firewalld tcp/udp protocol relationship*
- with only firewalld port=22 tcp open and firewalld running on both the nfs-server and nfs-client computers, a `mount server:/data /data` will fail (because port 2049 tcp is not open) but a `mount -o rdma server:/data /data` is successful

  - on the client the rdma `mount` shows `server:/data on /data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=rdma,port=20049,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.2,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.1)`
  - this is in RHEL 8.7
  - my observation seems to prove nfs via rdma is not affected by firewalld.  is this to be expected given how rdma is supposed to be *direct access* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDMA is technology to by-passing the kernel , and iptables is a module of the linux kernel , so firewalld will not work for any RDMA connections.